# Method Not Found when using MOQ in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am having trouble setting up a unit test where I need to Moq the HttpClient. In my code I have a decorator for the HttpClient which follows an interface.

```
public class WHttpClient: IWHttpClient{
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    ...
    public async Task<HttpReponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(string url, T content)
    {
        //Do Something
        return await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, content);
    }
    ...
}

public interface IWHttpClient{
    HttpRequestHeaders DefaultRequestHeaders {get;}
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsXmlAsync<T>(string url, T content);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(string url, T content);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync<T>(string url, T content);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url);
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url);
    Task<T> ReadAsAsync<T>(HttpResponseMessage response);
    T Read<T>(HttpResponseMessage response);
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private class WorkClass
    {
        private IWHttpClient _client;
        public WorkClass(IWHttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }
        public void DoWork()
        {
            var url = "DUMMY";
            var content = new ObjectToSerialize();
            Task.Run(() => _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, content));
        }

    }
    public class ObjectToSerialize
    {

    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Mock<IWHttpClient> _webClientMock = new Mock<IWHttpClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        var url = "DUMMY";
        var content = new ObjectToSerialize();
        _webClientMock.Setup(x => x.PostAsJsonAsync(url, It.IsAny<ObjectToSerialize>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)));
        var myClassToTest = new WorkClass(_webClientMock.Object);
        myClassToTest.DoWork();
    }
}
```

It successfully builds, but when I run the test, it gives me the exception:
**System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1 SomeNamespace.IWHttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(System.String, !!0)'.**

I've spent hours trying to figure out why I get this exception when I run the test. I have performed a clean and rebuild of my solution and yet it still appears as well as replacing the inputs in the mocksetup with:

```
(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>())
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?
Results from running:
[image]

Comment: I just ran what you provided and it passes the test with no exceptions.

Comment: @Nkosi - I don't know, I'm running the exact same code as above now in Visual Studio and its still giving me the exception still.

Comment: What version of Mpq are you using

Comment: @Nkosi - Moq v4.8.0, MSTest.TestAdapter v1.2.0, MSTest.TestFramework v1.2.0, Visual Studio 2017 v15.5.1

Comment: While your example now is somewhat complete I get the impression that it is not a true representation of your subject under test.

Comment: Well.. I added a screenshot to show what happens when I run that sample code I provided. The interface is entirely provided in the question.

Comment: Try reinstalling moq.

Comment: Just reinstalled Moq and Castle.Core. The same thing still happens :(

Comment: At this point I am unable to reproduce the error. Not sure what else is there. Will need to do some more research.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your quick responses though!

Comment: Did some looking and this issue on Githut should be of some interest to you. Others with similar problem and a potential solution. https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/566#issuecomment-355402114

Comment: Thank you very much. I resolved my issue.

Comment: What was the resolution.

Comment: I created a new test project and migrated all the unit tests over and it started working. As to what was actually fixed, I have no idea since all the project properties and configuration is the same (even the .proj file).

Answer (score 1):

The following minimal example was just to try and reproduce your problem as well as demonstrate how to exercise tests like this.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {

    private class WorkClass {
        private IWHttpClient _client;
        public WorkClass(IWHttpClient client) {
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task DoWork() {
            var url = "DUMMY";
            var content = new ObjectToSerialize();
            var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, content);
        }
    }

    public class ObjectToSerialize {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task MyTestMethod() {
        //Arrange
        var expectedResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var _webClientMock = new Mock<IWHttpClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        _webClientMock
            .Setup(_ => _.PostAsJsonAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<ObjectToSerialize>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(expectedResponse)
            .Verifiable();
        var myClassToTest = new WorkClass(_webClientMock.Object);

        //Act
        await myClassToTest.DoWork();

        //Assert
        _webClientMock.Verify();
    }
}
```

When exercised the test behaved as expected and passed. Even when the setup was changed to

```
.Setup(_ => _.PostAsJsonAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
```

Review and compare to your current test to help identify where possible mistakes may have been made.